# Picklist Doesn't Show All Values

Tags: visualforce, picklist, dependent-picklist

I have an issue. I have two sandboxes. In one I have a `Visualforce Page` with a dependent picklist, and it shows me the values inside. In th other sandbox with the same data inside (I deployed it over), I don't see the value in the `Visualforce Page`. I don't have a record type associated, and the page and the controller are the same. Any advice?

Comment: Perhaps field level security? Could you make sure your profile has the coeect field permissions?

Comment: Did you deploy it with change sets? If you did, all deployed fields will not be visible (even to System Admin) without adjusting field level security.

Comment: re: changeset deployment - if deployed `without` Profiles, fields won't be visible in target org

Comment: i tried the field level security and it is the same, the permission set too @sfdcfox. I haven't deploy it, it was a job's organizzation, can i do something to check it?